# Remove Duplicated Words From NSString and Save as New NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have scenarios in which I may have an NSString that contains several words, some of them duplicated.  What I want to do is take a string that looks like:

```
One Two Three Three Three Two Two Two One One Two Three
```

and make it look like:

```
One Two Three
```

There may be times that the exact length of the original NSString is different as well.  What I have so far is:

```
NSString *hereitis = @"First Second Third Second Third First First First";
    NSArray *words = [hereitis componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSCountedSet *countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:words];
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[words count]];

for(id obj in countedSet) {
    if([countedSet countForObject:obj] == 1) {
        [finalArray addObject:obj];
    }
}
NSString *string = [finalArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"String%@", string);
```

This however, just returns String in my array, and not ANY of the words.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `countForObject` to be `== 1`? Don't you just simply want it to be `>= 1`? I think the issue here might be that the count for your words is 3~5, and so you're not adding any of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can actually be done way less painlessly. NSSet doesn't allow duplicate entries. So, you can break the string into an array, and use that array to create the set. From there, all you have to do is convert back, and the dupes will be removed.

```
NSString *inputString = @"One Two Three Three Three Two Two Two One One Two Three";
NSSet *aSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
NSString *outputString = [aSet.allObjects componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"___%@___",outputString); // Outputs "___One Two Three___"
```

Comment: +1 No need to duplicate the behavior that a `set` will provide for you.

Comment: This is largely working, but has the issue of adding a space in front of the very first word, which is something that I really don't need.  Any advice for getting that out?

Comment: @user717452 Are you doing anything differently then what I've shown? This code on its own will not exhibit that behavior. I've edited my post to reflect the exact behavior of this code.

Comment: Did everything you showed, but for some reason added a space at the beginning.  I remedied with doing a substringFromIndex:1 on it.

Comment: I am able to remove the duplicate words using Set, but words are not in proper order. I tired using NSOrderedSet. How do i get the string in proper order?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an array of strings then

```
for(id obj in countedSet) {
    if([countedSet countForObject:obj] == 1) {
        [finalArray addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

After that you can use your words

```
NSLog(@"%@", finalArray[0]); //log 'One'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KVC Collection Operators](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) for this as well:

```
NSString *string = @"One Two Three Three Three Two Two Two One One Two Three";
NSArray *items = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSArray *uniqueItems = [items valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```